# Replacing .at() with [] throughout my code

Tags: c++, perl, sed, awk

I'm a C++ user and got some code that uses `.at()` to get bound checking on the STL vectors. Now I'd like to change them to standard `[]`. Does anyone know of a script that could do this? It doesn't have to be a super general script — most of the cases are `.at(i)` or perhaps `.at(a*i+j)` — but there are too many of them to do by hand.

Comment: What's wrong with `s,\.at\(i\),\[i\],g` ?

Comment: That only works with a single variable name. He probably wants something that uses back-references.

Comment: why do you want to do this? if for performance improvement, please check it by before converting and after, and if difference is less than 20% I would recommend to revert changes

Comment: If the code is using `at` to get bounds checking, aren't you going to have to add manual index checks as well at every site? Otherwise you are replacing bounds checking with well defined behaviour with potential _undefined behavior_.

Comment: The question seems to have been answered. Please accept one of the answers in the interest of maintaining the goals of this website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this Perl operator:

```
s/\.at\(([^)]+)\)/[$1]/g
```

The `s///` operator in Perl is a "substitute" (find/replace). In the first set of //, you specify the regular expression to match. The second // is the text to replace or substitute that match with.

In this case, I'm finding any instance of ".at(anything-but-a-close-paren)" and replace it with "[what-was-in-those-parens]".

As a one-liner,

```
perl -pe's/\.at\(([^)]+)\)/[$1]/g' in.cpp > out.cpp
```

**If you use Visual Studio**, do this in the Find/Replace prompt:

Find What: `\.at\({[^)]+}\)`
Replace with: `\[\1\]`

Enable Regular Expressions and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's,\.at(\([^\)]*\)),[\1],g' *.h *.cpp
```

should work for most simple expressions. However, if you use parentheses inside the parameter to at(), this will not work.

```
grep 'at(.*).*)' *.h *.cpp
```

helps you to identify these cases and convert them **before** running said sed script.

P.S. Keep a backup around (e.g. via a VCS) if you let sed operate in-place like here.

EDIT: Should have tested that sed script before posting. Fixed now, and tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/\.at(\([^)]*\))/\[\1]/g
```